# ¿como puedo ingresar al storage de un proyecto estando trabajando en otro distinto?

Tags: laravel, linux

quiero ingresar al storage de otro proyecto, por ejemplo trabajamos en linux y cada proyecto esta en la carpeta "www" donde se encuentra el proyecto 1, proyecto 2, proyecto 3, lo que quiero saber es como entrar al storage del proyecto 1 estando trabajando en el proyecto 2.

Comment: crear un link simbolico

Comment: O creando otros driver para esos directorios así los diferencias por nombre.